# How to construct consecutive pairs from a vector with last element included

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two vector as examples:

```
x <- c("a","b","c")
y <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

What I want to do is to construct a data frame with consecutive pair

```
# for X
a b
b c
c a

# for Y
a b
b c
c d
d a
```

I tried this but not quite get what I want.

```
> cbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1])
 [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "b" 
 [2,] "b"  "c" 

> cbind(y[-length(y)], y[-1])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c" 
[3,] "c"  "d"
```

Notice I missed the last element pair (e.g. `c a` for `X`and `d a` for `Y`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
cbind(x, c(x[-1], x[1]))
```